# Amazon CloudFront and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

I am new to Amazon AWS and am trying to setup a system to upload images for users. After setting up everything, I am unable to validate a token. Below, I will explain all of the configuration I have done.

I created an S3 bucket and I configured the CORS for that bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Next, I setup a CloudFront distribution that points to this S3 bucket. It is set to allow all HTTP methods (which includes "PUT"). An origin access identity is also created so that images are only viewable by the CloudFront url, instead of S3.

I then created an IAM user and have created a policy for that user so that I can request temporary credentials when I need to upload an image via CloudFront:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1504225496000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For now, I set the permissions to full access just for development. Eventually I will add more tighter permissions.

Once this is complete, I then request temporary credentials from an API like so:

```
var securityClient =
                new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(Variables.AWSUserWriteId, Variables.AWSUserWriteKey);

            var request = new GetSessionTokenRequest
            {
                DurationSeconds = 900
            };

            var tempCredentials = await securityClient.GetSessionTokenAsync(request);
            return new ApiResponse(Enums.ResponseStatus.Success, new JObject
            {
                {"id", tempCredentials.Credentials.AccessKeyId},
                {"key", tempCredentials.Credentials.SecretAccessKey},
                {"token", tempCredentials.Credentials.SessionToken}
            }, null);
```

This is returned to the browser client (note, I am able to successfully get the three values).

Using these values, I use the AWS-SDK to call the upload process:

```
let id = response.data.JsonData.id;
        let key = response.data.JsonData.key;
        let token = response.data.JsonData.token;

        let s3 = new AWS.S3({
            accessKeyId: id,
            secretAccessKey: key,
            sessionToken: token,
            endpoint: cloudFrontUrl //https://d3goqf5vihdmh2.cloudfront.net
        });
        s3.upload({Body: file, Bucket: amazonS3BucketName, Key: file.name}, (err, data) => {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(data);
            let hello = "hello";
        }).on("httpUploadProgress", evt => {
            console.log(evt);
        });
```

However, after doing all this, an error is returned:

```
"The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid."
```

The user has full permissions, and as far as I can tell, I should have everything setup correctly, unless I am missing something? I cannot find a solution anywhere after a search on google and documentation, I am completely stuck here.

EDIT: Here is more information of the requests actually going out. These are the request headers as provided by Google Browser Dev Tools:

```
:authority:d3goqf5vihdmh2.cloudfront.net
:method:PUT
:path:/**removingforprivacy**.development/**removingforprivacy**.png
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
authorization:AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=**removingforprivacy**/20170901/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-
amz-security-token;x-amz-user-agent, 
Signature=180d55d69eb0577b77d14b8938c675cbd8798924132c7367d02fbd59b5e8a3d3
content-length:33041
content-type:application/octet-stream
origin:http://localhost:3000
referer:http://localhost:3000/postnew
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date:20170901T024531Z
x-amz-security-token:FQoDYXdzEMz//////////wEaDDJE64k3fztWLnZWJiKrAbIUNroRDzBfHcFJrPTUIgNSKFWdZDM4Nt0a7UCxwnWopLRDJAMiwt/gX1svqe5ZJsUL+yHTubJylLVvIIZdxsGGCeSZhmaquyd5jWsx9n+PeHB5MFbxkcDdRWhaQ8eXobABH0Q53xxH/zBXxIZTn/qEERgHPjfaPVLLmzQmbd6+toc/WQX5y3HZMvf7ZgTh3KdoHWDwJEmCeYx6NuyNpR9NIiubVvI/2gH8zijGk6PNBQ==
x-amz-user-agent:aws-sdk-js/2.107.0 callback
```

Comment: *`endpoint: cloudFrontUrl`* isn't valid, here... You're mixing two different concepts.  To authorize a request sent through CloudFront, you need a CloudFront signed URL, which uses a different algorithm.  This in turn is problematic because a CloudFront URL is valid for any method the origin access identity can perform, per the bucket policy.

Comment: Thanks for the information. What would be the suggested way about going with this? I don't really need to secure get operations, however for adding and deleting I would like to secure this and I would like to do all operations via CloudFront. I guess I can go ahead and just do the adds and deletes directly on S3, and gets on CloudFront and live with the fact that a user can access objects by S3 and CloudFront URLs, unless there is a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: I'm working up a full explanation with some of the available options.  Can you clarify why you want to do all operations via CloudFront?  There's nothing wrong with that approach, and it has some advantages, but some people assume that uploads through CloudFront interact with the cache, but they don't.  Also, your price class selection and location of buckets and users might make S3 Transfer Acceleration a better choice for uploads.  It is exactly the same technology as uploads through CloudFront (it uses the CloudFront network), but a potentially more favorable pricing model.  Your thoughts?

Comment: Looks like I completely glossed over that piece about transfer acceleration. Thanks for that info. Does this mean that I can use the temporary credentials, with transfer acceleration enabled, with the JavaScript sdk just as I would by directly uploading to S3? I am assuming I won't have to face the same dilemma as I am with CloudFront, but just wanted to confirm. I am also assuming I can have both CloudFront for get requests, and enable transfer acceleration for put and delete requests?

Comment: Correct.  There is one "catch" with transfer acceleration -- don't use any dots in your bucket name.  Transfer Acceleration enables two new endpoints, `example-bucket.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com` and `example-bucker.s3-accelerate.dualstack.amazonaws.com`.  The signed URLs use the same agorithm as standard S3 signed URLs.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you need to use the SQS Queue Service in order to hand out temporary security credentials. See the following here Using 
[Temporary Security Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-using-temporary-security-credentials.html)

Comment: SQS doesn't hand out temporary security credentials. That would be a weird feature of a simple queue service. The STS service hands those out. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html The article you linked discusses using credentials from STS to access the SQS service.